# Whats the name of the dropdown panel with the IM status?

Tags: indicator, empathy, pidgin

So I'm trying to work out whats the name of the drop down panel in Ubuntu, the one that lets you set your IM status (online, offline, invisible etc etc).

I was on 12.04 and replaced Empathy with Pidgin easy enough, and this still kept the options in this bar, however when I upgraded to 12.10 beta 3 the bar has now dissapeared, but before I can search for answers I need to know what I can search for :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and Ubuntu 11.10, this is the **Messaging Menu**. It contains menu items relating both to instant messaging and to email (and a couple of other, somewhat related tasks).

Before that, there was the **Me Menu**, which contained instant messaging menu items and also provided access to account settings.

See [this article](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/07/ubuntu-11-10-menu-goodbye) for details. (That article does not cover the changes that are coming in Ubuntu 12.10, though--it's much too old for that.)